# How to match two data frames based on substrings within groups

Tags: r, string, match, grouping, partial

I want to merge two dataframes which are grouped by the same identifier. The variable in the first dataframe (valueA) should match with a substring of a variable in the second data frame (valueB), but only within groups.

I could manage to match the matching variables, but I'm struggling to limit the matching to the grouping variable. Here are the sample data frames and the matching code:

```
df1 <- data.frame(report = c('Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1'),
            identifier = c('Abraham', 'Abraham', 'Abraham','Barack', 'Barack','Barack'),
            variableA = c('V1','V2','V3','V1','V2', 'V3'),
            value = c('CDKN2A/B','PALB2','KRAS','TP53','RB1','KRAS'))

df2 <- data.frame(report = c('Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1'),
            identifier = c('Abraham', 'Abraham', 'Abraham','Abraham','Barack', 'Barack','Barack'),
            variableB = c('F1','F2','F3','F4','F1','F2', 'F3'),
            valueB = c('CDKN2A/B LOSS','PALB2 P1111FS*13','KRAS G12R','PALB2 N540FS*1','RB1 SPLICE SITE 2325+1G>A','KRAS G13C','TP53 C238F'))
```

Here is the code I've tried, but which is not working for groups

```
idx2 <- sapply(df1$value, grep, df2$valueB)
idx1 <- sapply(seq_along(idx2), function(i) rep(i, length(idx2[[i]])))
idx3 <- cbind(df1[unlist(idx1),,drop=F], df2[unlist(idx2),,drop=F])
```

Expected output is (code for data frame)

```
df3 <- data.frame(report=c('Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1','Report1'),
                  identifier = c('Abraham', 'Abraham', 'Abraham','Abraham','Barack', 'Barack','Barack'),
                  variableA = c('V1','V2','V3','V2','V1','V2', 'V3'),
                  value = c('CDKN2A/B','PALB2','KRAS','PALB2','TP53','RB1','KRAS'),
                  variableB = c('F1','F2','F3','F4','F1','F2', 'F3'),
                  valueB = c('CDKN2A/B LOSS','PALB2 P1111FS*13','KRAS G12R','PALB2 N540FS*1','TP53 C238F','RB1 SPLICE SITE 2325+1G>A','KRAS G13C'))
```

resulting dataframe

```
report  identifier  variableA   value   variableB   valueB
Report1 Abraham     V1      CDKN2A/B    F1  CDKN2A/B LOSS
Report1 Abraham     V2      PALB2   F2  PALB2   P1111FS*13
Report1 Abraham     V3      KRAS    F3  KRAS    G12R
Report1 Abraham     V2      PALB2   F4  PALB2   N540FS*1
Report1 Barack      V1      TP53    F1  TP53    C238F
Report1 Barack      V2      RB1 F2  RB1 SPLICE SITE 2325+1G>A
Report1 Barack      V3      KRAS    F3  KRAS    G13C
```

Hope this makes sense, many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `fuzzyjoin`-package for this:

```
fuzzy_inner_join(df2, df1, by = c("valueB" = "valueA", "identifier" = "identifier"), match_fun = list(str_detect, `==`)) %>%
  select(report.x, identifier.x, variableA, valueA, variableB, valueB)

  report.x identifier.x variableA   valueA variableB                    valueB
1  Report1      Abraham        V1 CDKN2A/B        F1             CDKN2A/B LOSS
2  Report1      Abraham        V2    PALB2        F2          PALB2 P1111FS*13
3  Report1      Abraham        V3     KRAS        F3                 KRAS G12R
4  Report1      Abraham        V2    PALB2        F4            PALB2 N540FS*1
5  Report1       Barack        V2      RB1        F1 RB1 SPLICE SITE 2325+1G>A
6  Report1       Barack        V3     KRAS        F2                 KRAS G13C
7  Report1       Barack        V1     TP53        F3                TP53 C238F
```

This way you can apply different matching functions for different columns. In this case we used `str_detect()` for your fuzzy matching column and `==` for your grouping column.

Comment: Thanks @Humpel, I got the following error: Error: All columns in a tibble must be 1d or 2d objects:
* Column `col` is NULL
Call `rlang::last_error()` to see a backtrace. Possibly an issue because it's a data frame?

Comment: Not sure, this doesn't even seem to be a `fuzzyjoin`-error. Maybe your sample data and true data are different? You columns need to be `character`, but that's not the cause of this error.

Comment: He says so in his explanation in the beginning. So I assumed it was a typo in the sample data. Forgot to mention it. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, the column name was the reason. But now I got a new error: Error in UseMethod("type") :  no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"

Comment: @Zipfer do `fuzzy_inner_join(mutate_all(df2,as.character), mutate_all(df1,as.character), by = c("valueB" = "value", "identifier" = "identifier"), match_fun = list(str_detect, \`==\`))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_extract` to capture the common string and merge on that, i.e.

```
library(stringr)

merge(df1, 
      transform(df2, value = sapply(df2$valueB, function(i)
                                  str_extract(i, paste(df1$value, collapse = '|')))), 
       by = c('value', 'identifier', 'report'))

#         value identifier  report variableA variableB                    valueB
#    1 CDKN2A/B    Abraham Report1        V1        F1             CDKN2A/B LOSS
#    2     KRAS    Abraham Report1        V3        F3                 KRAS G12R
#    3     KRAS     Barack Report1        V3        F2                 KRAS G13C
#    4    PALB2    Abraham Report1        V2        F2          PALB2 P1111FS*13
#    5    PALB2    Abraham Report1        V2        F4            PALB2 N540FS*1
#    6      RB1     Barack Report1        V2        F1 RB1 SPLICE SITE 2325+1G>A
#    7     TP53     Barack Report1        V1        F3                TP53 C238F
```